# Kill an App with background Services

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application where also running 5 background services. Base service class contains method:

```
public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    StopSelf();
}
```

Above code is working when application is being closed by user - servcies are being stopped. However I have implemeted another feature - user can close an application from itself. To achive that I have found this part of code to use:

```
Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
```

Application is being closed while debugging but after application is released there is magic sign

> " Application has stopped ".

After some reading I figured out it has to be something with services. Did somone faced similar issue 
?

Comment: why on earth would you kill the process instead of gracefully stopping the app

Comment: Do not kill process , simply use finish() method and override onDestroy()  method  of activity life cycle and  in onDestroy() method  stop background services you want to stop..

Comment: I am not experienced with android but when i call Finish() on currnet activity i still have another activity which will be shown ?

Comment: use finishAffinity() where you want to close the app but not the services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Finish() method for activity and call StopService() method for stop particular service

Comment: I did but I have another activity opened adn the anothre one is shown after close current.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: and in AnotherActivity   if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    finish();  
}